# SwiftUI If the scroll view has a header, it will be overlaid on the header when doing ScrollTo(id:)

Tags: swift, swiftui

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
      FirstTabView()
    }
}

struct FirstTabView: View {
    let items = (0..<40)
    var body: some View {
        ScrollViewReader(content: { proxy in
            ScrollView {
              LazyVStack(pinnedViews: [.sectionHeaders]) {
                Section(header: header().id("Header")
                  .onTapGesture {
                    proxy.scrollTo(20, anchor: .top)
                  }
                ) {
                    ForEach(items,id: \.self) {(item) in
                        Text("Item is \(item)")
                        .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 44)
                        .padding(.horizontal)
                        .background(Color.red)
                        .id(item)
                      
                    }
                }
              }
    
            }
            .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width)
        })
    }
  
    func header() -> some View {
        HStack {
            Text("Header")
                .bold()
            Spacer()
        }.padding([.top,.bottom])
    }
}
```

When I do ScrollTo(id:), I want the item to come under the pinned header. Is there a solution? Help

tried -> scrollTo(id: 20, anchor: .top)
expected to happen -> 20 rows below HeaderView

actually resulted -> It overlaps the HeaderView